# Captura de eventos em um botão

Tags: java, swing, gui

Estou iniciando em GUI em Java e queria entender como funciona a captura de eventos em um botão, como por exemplo no código abaixo:

**SimpleGui1.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGui1 implements ActionListener {

    JButton button;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        SimpleGui1 gui = new SimpleGui1();
        gui.go();

    } // fim do método main

    public void go() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton( "click me" );

        button.addActionListener( this );

        frame.getContentPane().add( button );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize( 300, 300 );
        frame.setVisible( true );

    } // fim do método go

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { // Aqui está minha dúvida
                                                     // Em que momento é chamado o
        button.setText( "I've been clicked!" );      // método?

    } // fim do método actionPerformed

} // fim da classe SimpleGui1
```

Como funciona esta comunicação entre a **origem** do evento (botão) e o **ouvinte** do evento?

Interface `ActionListener` na documentação:

```
public abstract interface java.awt.event.ActionListener extends java.util.EventListener {

  // Method descriptor #8 (Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V
  public abstract void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent arg0);
}
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe um bom tutorial da Oracle sobre como instanciar e registrar *Listeners*, lidar com eventos, etc ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/)). Do ponto de vista conceitual eventos, produtores e *listeners* existem para separar a origem de um estímulo e os pontos da aplicação interessados em lidar com ele.

Em suma:

1. A hierarquia de componentes que implementam a funcionalidade do `JButton` (incluindo componentes nativos, o que não vem ao caso) recebem do Sistema Operacional uma notificação de *click*. Existe todo um trabalho acontecendo na JVM para saber que aquele *click* aconteceu dentro dos limites do `JButton`, em um momento que ele esteja ativo e visível e para o usuário, bem como para determinar se o `JButton` realmente deverá responder pelo evento dentro da hierarquia de componentes aninhados.
2. Todo `JComponent` possuí uma [EventListenerList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) contendo as classes interessadas em "escutar" por determinados tipos de eventos. Quando você chama `button.addActionListener`, o seu `ActionListener` é registrado nessa lista:

   ```
   public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
      listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, l);
   }
   ```
3. Um evento (que herda de `java.util.EventObject`; no caso um [ActionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html)) é criado contendo as informações relevantes do estímulo (a origem, tipo de evento, quando ocorreu, etc, etc, etc). Para o `JButton` isso costuma ocorrer ou no método `setPressed` na classe [DefaultButtonModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultButtonModel.html) ou no método `fireActionPerformed` da classe `AbstractButton` (caso você use um modelo *preguiçoso*, algo que novamente não vem ao caso):

   ```
   ActionEvent e = null;
   // ...
   e = new ActionEvent(AbstractButton.this,
                       ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
                       actionCommand,
                       event.getWhen(),
                       event.getModifiers());
   ```

   O interessante da implementação atual é que o próprio `AbstractButton` se registra para escutar eventos do modelo, simplesmente propagando os eventos gerados pelo modelo para os *listeners* registrados com ele (veja o código da classe interna [AbractButton.Handler](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/javax/swing/AbstractButton.java#AbstractButton.Handler) para entender o funcionamento dessa parte).
4. Cabe ao componente executar os `payloads` dos `Listeners` registrados. No caso do `JButton` isso também ocorre no método `fireActionPerformed`:

   ```
   protected void fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // Guaranteed to return a non-null array
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
        ActionEvent e = null;
        // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
        // those that are interested in this event
        for (int i = listeners.length-2; i>=0; i-=2) {
            if (listeners[i]==ActionListener.class) {
                // Lazily create the event:
                if (e == null) {
                    String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
                    if(actionCommand == null) {
                        actionCommand = getActionCommand();
                    }
                    e = // Código do item 3
                }
                ((ActionListener)listeners[i+1]).actionPerformed(e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Finalmente, nesse momento o polimorfismo entre em ação. Um dos `ActionListener`s registrados para o `JButton` será uma instância da classe `SimpleGui1` (que implementa a interface `ActionListener` e se registrou junto ao `JButton` no passo 2). Quando o método `actionPerformed` é chamado no passo 4, o *payload* que você criou é invocado, mudando o texto do botão.

   ```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
       button.setText("I've been clicked!");    
   }
   ```

Logo, para responder sua dúvida, o método `actionPerformed` é executado na linha `((ActionListener)listeners[i+1]).actionPerformed(e);` do método `fireActionPerformed` da classe `AbstractButton`.

Caso você esteja se perguntando o motivo de nenhum desses detalhes "obscuros" sobre como um `ActionListener` é invocado estarem no tutorial oficial da <strike>Sun</strike> Oracle, o motivo é encapsulamento. Esses são detalhes de implementação (que podem mudar). O que usuários das APIs precisam saber é que *payloads* devem ser escritos dentro dos métodos especificados pelos *Listeners*, e que esses *Listeners* devem ser registrados junto aos componentes que produzem os eventos consumidos pelos *Listeners*.